# undefined symbol when compiling C program

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I'm getting the following error when compiling the source code that follows and I don't understand why. Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong. I have defined the signature of the failing method before using it however the linker can not find the symbol.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_numberOfDays", referenced from:
      _main in determinetomorrow-240382.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

int numberOfDays(struct Date);
bool isLeapYear(struct Date);

int main (void) {


    struct Date today, tomorrow;
    printf("Enter todays date int format (mm dd yyyy): ");
    scanf("%i%i%i", &today.month, &today.day, &today.year);

    if(today.day != numberOfDays(today)) {
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year + 1;
    } else if(today.month == 12) {
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year + 1;
    } else {
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year;
    }

    printf("Tomorrow's date is %i/%i/%.2i. \n", tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, tomorrow.year % 100);

    return 0;
}

int numberOfDay(struct Date d) {
    int days;
    const int daysPerMonth[12] = 
        {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    if(isLeapYear(d) == true && d.month == 2)
        days = 29;
    else
        days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];

    return days;
}

bool isLeapYear(struct Date d) {
    bool leapYearFlag;

    if((d.year % 4 == 0 && d.year % 100 != 0) || d.year % 400 == 0)
        leapYearFlag = true;
    else
        leapYearFlag = false;

    return leapYearFlag;
}
```

Comment: Typo. The function is declared as `numberOfDays` and defined as `numberOfDay`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numberOfDays(struct Date);

int numberOfDay(struct Date d) {
    int days;
    const int daysPerMonth[12] = 
        {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    if(isLeapYear(d) == true && d.month == 2)
        days = 29;
    else
        days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];

    return days;
}
```

You have a typo in the function name.

Comment: Wow guess I should pay attention to details. Totally overlooked that.

Comment: A typo does not deserve an answer.

Comment: @RSahu Irrelevant comments.. don't deserve a comment.

Comment: @Inisheer, there is a reason why there is a close to vote option for problems caused by typos.